# Convert the "lite app" to "pro app" within the application

Tags: ios

I had two applications in the App Store. One is the free version, the other is the paid version.

I need to have a button in the application itself named "Upgrade".
**Can we offer members the ability to upgrade from lite to pro within the app using in-App purchase, whenever a user clicks on that button?**

Do we have any methods directly in iOS-6 ? Can we do this ?

Comment: Sun Tzu once said, "Know thy enemy". I would suggest you do some research on your marketing platform (the app store) and redesign how you are deploying this product. You will quickly see having Free/Paid apps is not how the successful apps work. Have you ever seen an upgrade (and then download our other app) button in a good app in the last five years?

Comment: @Matt. taken, not took.

Comment: @PauldeLange It's not my primary language. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can hide all features in lite version those features you want to show in Pro version.
Then when user click on upgrade button then on that button you write your in-app-purchase mechanism. Once user successfully purchase your up-gradation pack then un-hide those pro features in lite version. Then your app will become pro version. 
Now ***its completely depending on your logic and code skills how to hide and unhide features***.
See related links :-

[Convert existing iOS paid app to freemium model with in-app purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735635/convert-existing-ios-paid-app-to-freemium-model-with-in-app-purchase)

[How do I manage building a Lite vs Paid version of an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549462/how-do-i-manage-building-a-lite-vs-paid-version-of-an-iphone-app)

Comment: Let's suppose that if app has more than 100 features that which makes difference to show in the lite and pro.. Then, as per you said, we need to change all the features that differs in the app rite ??

Comment: @Manohar, read my last line in 1st paragraph. "its totally depending on your logic and code skills how to hide and unhide features"

Comment: @iAmbitious 
 Thax for your reply ... but what about sever side ...... my coding is ok but server side  also we need to manage ?

Comment: @Nag_iphone, its depending on your app design. But i don't thing so your required server side changes. You can manage everything in your app. See my shared links as well.

Answer (score 5):

See first of all if you want Lite & Pro version of the Application there is no need to Upload 2 separate Applications for lite & Pro if you are using InApp purchase do the following:

1. Keep Application with All Pro features
2. keep 1 button as you need it with title Upgrade with Pro version with
   inApp purchase in Action
3. Disable All Pro Feature & check the conditions when user purchase
   Pro version then Pro features will be enabled.

What happen with this is if user will not purchase the Pro by pressing Upgrade button they can use lite version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @mayuraa... problem is the i download the videos from one suporrted site for free version ,some of the sites are not supported for free version this depends upon server side  ....how can i manage?

Comment: @Nag_iphone for that you have to check for some unique data that comes with the video information. using that you can check the validations & manage lite+Pro version