# How can I convert free features to paid features in my ios app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I currently have a free app (game) in the Apple app store. I would like to begin charging for access to features that already exist within the app (in-app purchases). Ideally, users that have already downloaded the app would not have to pay to continue using these features. However, any new users would not have access to them without making a purchase. I would like to do this without creating another app in the app store. Is this possible and if so can someone provide high level steps for getting this set up?

Comment: Also, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3735635/558933. The answer points out that you can use the receipt from Apple to determine if someone bought the app before it went freemium and so whether they should get the features without having to buy an in-app purchase.

Comment: great - appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible and if so can someone provide high level steps for getting this set up?

Yes, it is possible. The high-level steps are:

1. Write an update to your existing app, in which those features are available only by in-app purchase.
2. Submit the update to the app store.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without forcing users who already have the app to pay? I assume when the existing users update they will suddenly be locked out from using those features. Let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: You could look for some NSUserDefaults entry that tells you that this user already existed.