# How to test receipt validation in this case?

Tags: ios, receipt-validation

I am working on converting an app from paid to free, with some of the former features under IAP. As a result, existing users need to have a copy of the IAP. In order to do this, I am using receipt validation code from [Apple's Website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html). My goal in this case is not to actually validate the receipt for legitimacy, but instead to get back the version number that the user bought so I can detect if they are a paid user (thank you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735635/convert-existing-ios-paid-app-to-freemium-model-with-in-app-purchase) for the suggestion).

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (!receipt) { NSLog(@"No receipt found"); return; }
```

This is the code I am using to get the user's receipt. It is near-identical to the code on the above official apple site. However, I still want to test it and the code following it, which grants the user their IAP.

However, the above code will log "No receipt found" and return if I run the program in the Simulator, on my iPhone via Xcode, or on my iPhone via TestFlight. I installed the current App Store version, then tried TestFlight, and it still gave the same no-receipt error.

How do I get a copy of the receipt for testing, and moreover, how would I test this form of receipt validation?

Comment: As far as I know a dev build will not have a receipt available until you complete an IAP in the sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SKReceiptRefreshRequest will provide a fake receipt, which you validate on apple's sandbox validation server. Calling SKReceiptRefreshRequest was the element I was missing.

```
SKReceiptRefreshRequest *receiptRequest = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] initWithReceiptProperties:nil];
receiptRequest.delegate = self;
[receiptRequest start];
```

-

```
- (void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request {
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (!receipt) { NSLog(@"No receipt found"); return; }
// Create the JSON object that describes the request
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *requestContents = @{
                                  @"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]
                                  };
NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                      options:0
                                                        error:&error];

if (!requestData) { NSLog(@"No request data found"); return; }

// Create a POST request with the receipt data.
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
[storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];
// Make a connection to the iTunes Store on a background queue.
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:storeRequest queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           if (connectionError) {
                               NSLog(@"Connection error");
                               return;
                           } else {
                               NSError *error;
                               NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
                               if (!jsonResponse) { return; }
                               NSLog(@"JsonResponce: %@",jsonResponse);
                               NSString *version = jsonResponse[@"receipt"][@"original_application_version"];
                               //found version number! Do whatever with it!
                           }
                       }];
```